# dynamically expand element with hidden overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

I've got an element with `overflow: hidden`, which I'd like to expand when clicked.

This is what I have so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/up6bW/2/

It does expand the element, but not as it's supposed to. It should not push the element below it, but overlap and hide it. I can make this work partially by using `position: absolute`, but this makes the next element collapse to the top.

Can this be done by only using CSS on the clicked element? Other elements should not be adjusted.
Or if they are, this should be calculated automatically using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this solution, which automatically adds padding to the next element.

http://jsfiddle.net/up6bW/47/

HTML

```
<div class="a" onclick="z(this)">click here click here click here</div>
<div>1234567890</div>
<div>1234567890</div>
<div>1234567890</div>
<div class="a" onclick="z(this)">click here click here click here</div>
<div>1234567890</div>
<div>1234567890</div>
<div>1234567890</div>
<div class="a" onclick="z(this)">click here click here click here</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    word-break: break-all;
}

div.a {
    color: tomato;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function z (a) {

    // nextElementSibling equivalent
    var b = a.nextSibling;
    while (b && b.nodeType != 1)
        b = b.nextSibling;

    if (b)
        b.style.cssText = b.style.paddingTop ? "" : "padding-top: " + a.clientHeight + "px";

    a.style.cssText = a.style.border ? "" : "\
        background: #fff;\
        border: 1px solid #ccc;\
        height: auto;\
        margin-left: -5px;\
        margin-top: -5px;\
        padding: 4px;\
        position: absolute;\
        ";

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what you might need: 
http://jsfiddle.net/up6bW/39/

All I did was make the position:absolute on your dropdown Div and then gave the first of the other divs a padding on top to compensate for the loss of space from the absolute positioning:

First you can change your second div a bit to add a class:

```
<div class="a" onclick="z(this)">click here click here click here click here click here</div>
<div class="second">1234567890</div>
<div>1234567890</div>
<div>1234567890</div>
<div>1234567890</div>
<div>1234567890</div>
```

​
Then change the CSS to something like this:

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

div {
    width: 150px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    word-break: break-all;
}

div.a {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: tomato;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:absolute;
}
.second{
    padding:25px 0px 0px 0px;       
}​
```

The div you want to expand will have absolute positioning then the second div will have enough padding to make up for that first div.

Comment: What happens in IE8?  Is it a z-index problem?

Comment: It doesn't support the `nth-of-type` selector, apparently.

Comment: Ah, well you can make the first extra div have a class name and just change div:nth-of-type(2) to whatever the class name is.

Comment: Changed the code above.  It seems like the simplest solution on this page. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could also involve wrapping the div in a container like so:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="a" onclick="z(this)">
        click here click here click here click here click here
    </div>
</div>
<div>1234567890</div>
<div>1234567890</div>
<div>1234567890</div>
<div>1234567890</div>
<div>1234567890</div>
```

CSS:

```
body { margin: 10px; }

div { font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 150px; word-break: break-all; }

div.a { color: tomato; cursor: pointer; height: 20px; overflow: hidden; }
.container { height: 20px; overflow: visible; }
```

JS:

```
function z (a) {
    a.style.cssText = a.style.border ? "" : "\
        background: #fff;\
        border: 1px solid #ccc;\
        height: auto;\
        margin-left: -5px;\
        margin-top: -5px;\
        padding: 4px;\
        position: absolute;\
        ";
};
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/retaF/8/)

Obviously adding HTML elements for presentational reasons is less than ideal, but I think it's better than a JavaScript alternative.

Tested in IE7+, Chrome, and Firefox

Comment: It works well, but adds HTML, as you mentioned. I've chosen another solution which only slightly expands the already used JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0):

Placing elements on top of each other **requires** absolute positioning. You can put some `padding-top` on the first element to compensate for the positioning of the overlap.

Comment: CSS does not support click events. You still need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Can the CSS of the other elements be adjusted dynamically using JavaScript. I can add padding myself, but if multiple clicked elements are involved, this gets complicated quickly (and moreso when the CSS on the elements is changed at some point).

Comment: The padding you need should be a little greater than the height of the absolutely-positioned box, which you can get $().height() from, then set the $().css('height','...') to the same value.